# 3-way ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, relationship

I have 3 tables: dealers, brands and services. The tables are joined using table dealer_brand_service.

[Image of table relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcGRG.png)

- Dealer has many brands
- Brand has many services

**Dealer:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dealers")
@Data
public class Dealer extends BaseModel {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "brand_services_dealer", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dealer_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id"))
    private Set<VehicleBrand> brands;
}
```

**VehicleBrand:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "brands")
@Data
public class VehicleBrand extends BaseModel {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany    
    @JoinTable(name = "brand_services_dealer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "service_id"))
    private Set<VehicleService> services;
}
```

**VehicleService**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
@Data
public class VehicleService extends BaseModel {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

I believe this is not the greatest approach on associations, so I would like to hear your suggestions how should I associate this entities the more proper way. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just add an entity that represents dealer_brand_service table and connect it with one-to-many to the other tables

Comment: If dealer has many brands, and brands has many services, then you should have two join tables, not one. If for a given dealer and a given brand, you have many services, then you need an entity mapping this dealer_brand_service table.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this? I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Thanks